# MA and AR process stationarity intuition

Tags: sequences-and-series, stochastic-processes

$y_{MA}$ = $ε_t$ +  $ε_{t-1}$ <- stationary

$y_{AR}$ = $ε_t$ + $y_{AR_{t-1}}$

$y_{AR_{t-1}}$ = $ε_t$ +  $ε_{t-1}$ + $y_{AR_{t-2}}$

$y_{AR_{t-2}}$ = $ε_t$ +  $ε_{t-1}$ + $ε_{t-2}$ + $y_{AR_{t-3}}$ <- non-stationary?

etc.

The MA time series is stationary.  This makes sense to me because you're summing up normally distributed mean 0 random variables, but then, an AR process, if the $y_{AR_{t-i}}$ terms are all also sums of normally distributed mean 0 random variables, why is it non-stationary?  Again here, you're summing normally distributed mean 0 random variables.  I'm obviously not understanding something here, where is the flaw in my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an AR process, the *variance* changes (and, in fact, increases) over time.  Thus, for example,

$$\begin{align}
Var(y_{AR_t}) &= Var(\epsilon_t) + Var(y_{AR_{t-1}}) \\
&> Var(y_{AR_{t-1}}).
\end{align}$$

Since the definition of a [stationary process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process) is one whose probability distribution doesn't change under shifts in time, an AR process cannot be stationary.

You're right that the *mean* of $y_{AR_t}$ and $y_{AR_{t-1}}$ are both $0$, but stationary requires more than just the means being the same.

Comment: I realized what I was missing this morning.  In an MA process, each step consists of the sum of only two normally distributed mean 0 random variables, allowing the variance to stay constant.  Thanks for the response, it helped me arrive my improved understanding :)